# Is there a way just to show the webpack source file to chrome and not the legible React js code?

Tags: reactjs

I see a static folder in chrome dev tools for my site which has a js subfolder that shows all my react components.  I was under the impression that only the minified/webpack output file would be delivered to chrome.

Comment: How are you building your app? Are you using `npm` or `yarn`? What exact command?

Comment: I am using npm run build for a create react app and I deliver the html as a static file for a certain route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `devtool: 'none'` or if you're using webpack 4, you can try using `--production` flag (which effectively does the same thing) to disable sourcemaps. The legible code that you see is due to sourcemaps - your actual code is not being served.

Comment: Thanks, Mrchief.  I followed https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2005 to achieve something similar.